# How to undo changes in an arbitrary commit?

Tags: git

I have some commit that is several commits previous to `HEAD`.  While committing, there were a few changes that were staged that I had not noticed.  Looking through my `git log` I noticed these unwanted changes.  Searching google for `'undo changes for an arbitrary commit'`, returns many results on undoing an entire commit and removing changes in the index.  However, what would be a way to remove these changes in this arbitrary commit?

Comment: You mean you want to partially revert a commit? Do you want to rewrite history?

Comment: The command you are looking for is [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---interactive).

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't mind rewriting history.  these are all local changes and I don't want any added complexity such as reverting.  i simply want commit `AB3ej` to go from `{change1, change2, change3}` to `{change1, change2}`, for example..

Comment: @axiac that seems like a bit overkill for this use-case because i just want to make a change to one commit.

Comment: There are many ways of changing a past commit. `git rebase --interactive` is the safest and the most straight forward way. Git does the heavy lifting, all you have to do is to ask it to do it and then guide it.

Comment: @AlexBollbach you're not just making a change to one commit, because that commit is the parent of the next, which is the parent of the next, which ... If you alter one commit, you have to redo all subsequent commits. That's what rebasing does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure your working tree is clean. [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) helps you find this. It should not report any changes waiting to be committed. If there are changes you can either commit them (in a temporary branch if needed) or [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them.

After you make sure the working tree is clean, create a branch on the current commit but do not check it out:

```
$ git branch backup
```

It is not really needed, you can use the reflog instead, but it is easier (and more visible) this way. `backup` is just a name I chose for the branch, it is nothing special with it; the only constraint is that it must not already exist.

Assuming you want to modify the third commit in the past, run:

```
$ git rebase --interactive HEAD~4
```

Git opens in the default editor a temporary file whose content looks like this:

```
pick 7f0c5e794 the commit you want to change
pick 9f96dcae9 commit message #2
pick 02ed04062 commit message #3
pick beac35780 the most recent commit
```

This is the plan for the rebase. Of course, it contains the hashes and the subjects of your last three commits. They are the last four commits (because of `HEAD~4`) in the chronological order (older first).

Edit the line of the commit you want to modify (the first line); change `pick` to `edit` then save the file and exit the editor.

When you exit the editor, Git starts the rebasing. It checks out the commit `HEAD~3` and exits, allowing you to `edit` the commit, as you asked it in the plan.

Make the changes you want, stage them then run `git commit --amend` to modify the commit (your goal). The best way to do the changes is to run:

```
$ git reset --mixed HEAD~1
```

This brings the repo in the status it was before the commit you want to modify, with files changed in the working tree and nothing added to the index. Add to the index only the files you need and commit (**without** `--amend`). This is the "edited"<sup>1</sup> commit you wanted.

After you edit the commit you still have uncommitted changes in the working tree. You have to either commit them (create a new commit that didn't exist in the original history), stash them (and apply them after you complete the rebase) or discard them completely (`git reset --hard` does it; make sure you really don't need them before running this command).

After you resolve the problem of uncommitted changes one way or another, run:

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

Git continues the rebase; it processes the other commits as you have told it in the plan. Our plan mentions `pick` for the other commits and this means Git just applies the changes of these commits you don't want to modify.

If everything goes well, after this command completes you have a new history line that looks like you wanted. If it doesn't look like you wanted you can run

```
$ git reset --hard backup
```

to go back where you started from and start over.

If the rebase doesn't complete successfully (it may encounter conflicts) you can always abort it by running `git rebase --abort`. Git will undo all the changes and you will be where you started from (on the commit pointed at by the `backup` branch).

Or, you can solve the conflicts, commit and the run `git rebase --continue` until the rebase completes.

After you end the rebase one way or another and you are pleased with the result or have quit the idea of changing the past commit, run `git branch -D backup` to remove the backup branch.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Git commits are immutable. It is not possible to edit a commit. "Editing" a commit in fact creates a new commit that is used instead of the old one. Of course, the new commit has a different hash than the original.

The old commit is still present in the repository and it is accessible by its hash or by using a branch. When there is no branch that can be used to reach it and there is no reference to it in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), the commit object is removed on the next garbage collection cycle.

Comment: i'm slightly confused by the your steps around `$ git reset --mixed HEAD~1`.  at one point you recommend `git commit --amend` but later say commit with no amend.  Is there one or two commits associated with the 'edit commit' of this rebase?

Comment: When Git stops to let you modify the commit, the repo status is the same it was **after** the commit you want to edit was generated. You can either do some changes, stage them and use `git commit --amend` to modify the last commit (the one to edit) or you can go back one commit (using `git reset HEAD~1`) and generate a completely new commit instead of editing the existing one. The first option is good when you want to add files you missed or to make small fixes. The second one works better to remove changes from the commit.

Comment: ah i see, so `git commit --ammend` would allow me to add files, add changes, or change the commit message, but `git reset HEAD~1` will reset the commit history and allow me to delete (not re-add) the files I want gone from history and then commit normally.  since the original commit is immutable, a new commit (new hash) will replace the old one.  is that right?

Comment: Indeed, something like that. `git commit --amend` allows you to modify the commit currently pointed out by `HEAD` (the current commit). `git reset HEAD~1` moves `HEAD` to the parent of the current commit. After `git reset HEAD~1` use `git commit` without `--amend` because you don't want to modify the current commit. In all cases Git creates new commits. Even for the commits marked with `pick` in the rebase plan it creates new commits; they have different parents that the original commits and this leads to them having new IDs.